# C# 7.0 Overloads and the new tuple return syntax

Tags: c#, methods, syntax, tuples, overloading

Just a quick question about method overloading using the new C# 7.0 tuple syntax.

I have created two functions overloads. Simplified, they're along the lines of:

```
public Boolean TheFunction( string p_in_value )
    { 
    ... 
    return true;
    }
```

and

```
public ( Boolean Result, long SomeID ) TheFunction( string p_in_value )
    {
    ...
    return ( true, _found_id );
    }
```

Now, I would argue that since their respective calls would take the form(s)

```
_my_bool = TheFunction( "" );
```

and

```
( _my_bool, _my_long ) = TheFunction( "" );
```

that the compiler ought to be able to distinguish between the two, thus fulfilling the basic requirement that when creating overloads, one needs to be able to determine which version you want to call.

Now, I read in another question that as recently as C# 3.0 that the signature of a method does not include its return type, but surely that must no longer apply as I have functions elsewhere that have no problems:

```
public long ReadHive(string p_section, string p_setting, long p_default) {...}
public bool ReadHive(string p_section, string p_setting, bool p_default) {...}
```

Nonetheless, I'm getting the syntax error "'Program' already defines a member called 'TheFunction' with the same parameter types".

So unless I'm just looking at the wrong thing, it appears that with this new tuple return syntax, the return types play no part in distinguishing one version from another, which does rather look somewhat short-sighted.

So, my question - am I looking at the wrong thing and this should be possible, or am I out of luck and the new syntax just comes up short in this respect?  Or am I even more wrong and am missing some fundamental difference between how my "TheFunction" methods are  handled vs. how my "ReadHive" methods are handled?

Comment: its not the way the language/compiler was designed.

Comment: your `ReadHive` methods are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# never allowed methods to be different by only their return type. So what you are proposing is not going to compile in the first place.

There is only one exception to this, when implementing implicit conversions:

```
class Foo
{
    public static implicit operator int(Foo f)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(Foo f)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Compiler creates `op_implicit` methods that only differ by their return type, like this:

[image]

But that's not useful in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you add:

```
public long ReadHive(string p_section, string p_setting, long p_default) {...}
public bool ReadHive(string p_section, string p_setting, bool p_default) {...}
```

the functions are different by the params - third param is long vs. bool.

you cannot distinguish functions only by return type :(

Answer (score 0):

In my haste, I did indeed miss the fundamental difference between the parameter lists.  Sorry to have wasted your time.  Thank you all for your help - you are the best!  Too bad one can't include return type(s) as part of the identifying information, even though "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods" does state "The return value, or void if the method has none." is part of the signature. Perhaps that just doesn't mean what I thought it meant.  Again - thank you all, and sorry for just missing the obvious.  Perhaps after I've passed my second month C# programming I'll be better...